# Python calculating prime numbers

Tags: python

I have to define a function called is_prime that takes a number x as input, then for each number n from 2 to x - 1, test if x is evenly divisible by n.
If it is, return False. If none of them are, then return True.

The system I'm using (codecademy) has given my code the error message "Oops, try again. Does your is_prime function take exactly one argument (an integer)? Your code threw a "unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'list'" error."

Please could someone to fix my code with an explanation of how my code is wrong?

```
def is_prime(x):
    n = range(2, x-1)
    if x % n == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Also note that `range(a,b)` includes `a` but not `b`

Comment: Develop an algorithm on paper and run through it by hand before you start coding. This will help you notice things like when you need a loop and when you're trying to modulus an `int` by a `list` (which the error message explains pretty clearly anyway - on that note, pay close attention to Python's error messages, which are usually very good).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'm a beginner at python and I'm quite bad at it so I don't know how to develop an algorithm for coding at all

Comment: "Algorithm" doesn't mean "finished code." It's just the specific process you go through to determine a result. Write down the specific steps you would use to find a prime number in plain English. After you're comfortable with that, you can start figuring out how to put those instructions into the computer in a language it can understand.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thank you!

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 While _Python's_ error message is clear, it looks like Code Academy has added a "helpful" layer of misdirection by telling the user to check the parameters of `is_prime`, which has nothing whatsoever to do with the _actual_ error.  So I suppose a rule of thumb would be: Read the Python error message, ignore Code Academy's commentary.

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop over the range:

```
 def is_prime(x):
    if x < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2,x):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

`if x % i == 0` never evaluates to True, you have a prime so you return True outside the loop after you have checked each `i`. You could simply return a gen exp:

```
def is_prime(x):
    return x > 1 and not any(x % i == 0 for i in range(2, x))
```

Comment: Why are you still defining `n`?

Comment: "Oops, try again. Your function fails on is_prime(0). It returns None when it should return False."

Comment: @user5216189, there is no way it returns None, you just need to catch when x is less than 2

Comment: You could replace `and not any(x % i == 0 for...` with `and all(x % i for...` via De Morgan's Law.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, I was going to use all originally but thought it would be easier for the OP to understand if I kept the condition the same.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use range.

You want

```
def is_prime(x):
    for n in range(2, x-1):
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Range returns a list, so your original code was checking to see if the list object was evenly divisible by `n`, instead of checking each element of the list.

Comment: @khelwood Oops, that's what I get for not proofreading. It's fixed now.

Comment: "Oops, try again. Your function fails on is_prime(0). It returns None when it should return False." not sure how you could even fix that problem

Comment: @user5216189 That's called a "base case" and you should take care of it first, before the loop :P

Comment: @user5216189 That's a completely different problem.

Comment: @MorganThrapp have you any idea how I could fix this? It's giving the same message for the other code given

Comment: Check if x is 0 and return False? I'm not going to walk you through the tutorial, you're not going to learn anything that way.

Comment: @khelwood Yeah, I was trying to not give OP all the answers. Also, if you read the question, OP doesn't actually want prime numbers, they want some weird division thing.

Comment: @MorganThrapp fair enough