# 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having all sorts of trouble with this Python code, not good at coding, but have gone this far:

```
students = input("Students: ")
print('Class Roll')
myList = students.append()
myList.sort()
print(students[0])
print(students[1])
print(students[2])
print(students[3])
print(students[4])
```

List that it has to sort in order is: Peng Ivan Alan Jodi Macy

```
It comes back with this: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 12, in <module>
    myList = students.append()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Please help in easy to understand language, I need to have this right to progress onto the next round of code.

Comment: `input` should get the input from user which is of the type str

Comment: Do you mean `students.split()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Official Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html) to begin with.

> myList = students.append()

In this line, you are basically trying to create a list `myList` by appending nothing (since the parameter list is empty) to a string `students`.

*The following code is probably what you need as far as you have described in your question:*

```
students = input("Students: ")

myList = students.split()
myList.sort()

print('Class Roll')
for student in myList:
    print(student)
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend Codecademy. Their Python course and parser are really hit-or-miss, often leading to new SO questions.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Well, I do agree, sometimes their python parser does create problems by refusing to run fully valid codes. However, I feel it will be easier for beginners because there is no hassle of setting up Python, etc. Plus, they provide a proper guideline and practice questions to get started with Python. But obviously, for the seasoned programmer, the official tutorial is the way to go.

Comment: It also goes the other way, with their parser allowing bad code as long as it runs, e.g. ending each statement with a semicolon.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I never noticed that because I never tried it ... as a course on python, it should be checking such a mistake ... But, if you run python statements ending in semicolons in a python interpreter, even then semicolons are overlooked ... so perhaps, the programmer needs to be careful after all ... but the official tutorial is in fact the best way to learn in the long run, I agree ...

Comment: That's the point: it overlooks things that are wrong, just because they technically don't cause a traceback.

Comment: I have to agree, Codecademy is horrid as far as mistakes go, have had a lot of trouble with it. Must thank you for your answer to my question though @TigerhawkT3 it was similar to what I had first tried with on line not quite right, but now it works, heaps grateful.

Comment: Code Academy can be _especially_ bad for beginners, because it "helpfully" annotates Python's clear and precise error messages, suggesting where to look for the problem.  When these suggestions are [completely wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948212/python-calculating-prime-numbers), they send the student off on a wild goose chase.

Comment: I have edited my answer to remove the Codecadamy link. Hope it is alright now. It is just that I did not have to ask SO questions for completing the Codecadamy course; but then again, I already knew programming and was not a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html), which will explain functions, methods, and types. Briefly, you are trying to create a `list` by appending nothing to a string. You cannot do that. Perhaps the "students" you ask for is a space-delimited string, in which case you can create a `list` by simply using `split()` on it:

```
students = input('Students: ')
mylist = sorted(students.split())
print('Class Roll', *mylist, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Can understand what you are saying there, but I need to have code sort the names of all under one another, this code just puts each letter spaced under one another of one student. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I don't understand the issue you're having, particularly "puts each letter spaced under one another of one student."